# Publishing multiple server endpoints in one WSO2 API

Tags: api, wso2, publisher

I’m have two endpoints in a SOAP server implementation.

http://myhost.net:8081/configuration/v3.0/skills/SOAP?wsdl
http://myhost.net:8081/configuration/v3.0/termCodes/SOAP?wsdl

Can I publish them in one API using API Publisher, so my client only has to subscribe to one?

If so, what would I put in “Production URL”, and “URL Pattern” for the resources.  I’ve tried a lot of things, but nothing seems to work.

I’m currently trying to use:

```
Context = /configuration
Version = v3.0
Production URL = http://myhost.net:8081
URL Pattern = /termCodes/SOAP and /skill/SOAP
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you like to have a single API for multiple services..Currently, we don't have direct support in APIM for this feature.

But you can keep ESB in the middle, and create a proxy and point your 2 endpoints, and provide the proxy as your service endpoint at the API publisher

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Good to know it isn't directly supported - I'll stop trying to figure it out, and use a proxy instead.